# Haskell: Difference between hGetBuf, hGetBufSome and hGetBufNonBlocking

Tags: haskell

Can some body explain me the difference between hGetBuf and hGetBufSome. When to use hGetBuf, hGetBufSome, hGetBufNonBlocking?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Comming from the [documentation](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.8.0.0/docs/System-IO.html#v:hGetBuf) I think the difference is like this:

- `hGetBuf` blocks execution until either the specified number of bytes have been read or `EOF` is reached.
- `hGetBufSome` blocks execution until it can either read at least **some** bytes, or until `EOF` has been reached. It doesn't read more than the given number of bytes.
- `hGetBufNonBlocking` doesn't block execution. It tries to read the given number of bytes if any are available, but may return fewer.